# Error on Express Application "Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client"

Tags: node.js, express, header

I did intentionally return(so the userExists variable is True).
I have encountered this error many times, but I do not understand how it gets generated

In the logs, I have two errors with the same error message but different line

1. 

Error: *Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client*
line:

```
return res.status(200).json({
```

2. 

Error: *Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client*
line:

```
 return res.status(500).json({
```

Store_User Code:

```
const STORE_USER = async (req, res) => {
  try {
  
    const {
      name,
      surname,
      email,
      password,
      phone,
      country,
      city,
      address,
      zip,
      dob,
      gender,
    } = req.body;

    await prisma.$transaction(async (tx) => {
      const userExists = await tx.user.findFirst({
        where: {
          email,
        },
      });

      if (userExists) {  // userExists is True, so I guess it returned this
        return res.status(409).json({
          success: false,
          message: "User already exist",
          code: "B00001",
        });
      }

      const password_hashed = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);

      const user = await tx.user.create({
        data: {
          name,
          surname,
          email,
          password: password_hashed,
          gender,
          phone,         
          address,
          zip,
        },
      });

       const token = crypto.randomBytes(30).toString("hex");

      await tx.verify_Account.create({
        data: {
          Users: {
            connect: {
              id: user.id,
            },
          },
          token,
        },
      });



    return res.status(200).json({
      success: true,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return res.status(500).json({
      success: false,
      code: "A00010",
    });
  }
};
```

Can someone explain how does this error encounter?
So it send two requests the 200 and the 500, but I do not understand because I return when userExist is True

If I try without transactions I do not encounter any error:
So with this code:

I just tried without prisma transactions the code is okay and I do not get the header error.

```
const STORE_USER = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array(), success: false });
    }

    const {
      name,
      surname,
      email,
      password,
      phone,
      country,
      city,
      address,
      zip,
      dob,
      gender,
    } = req.body;

    const userExists = await prisma.user.findFirst({
      where: {
        email,
      },
    });

    if (userExists) {
      console.log("TEST1");
      return res.status(409).json({
        success: false,
        message: "User already exist",
        code: "B00001",
      });
    }

    console.log("TEST2");

    const clientRole = await prisma.role.findFirst({
      where: {
        name: "client",
      },
    });

    if (!clientRole) {
      console.log("Role not found");
      return res.status(500).json({
        success: false,
        code: "A00010",
      });
    }
    // TODO! CHECK IF COUNTRY AND CITY EXIST

    const date_date_of_birth = new Date(dob);

    const password_hashed = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);

    const user = await prisma.user.create({
      data: {
        name,
        surname,
        email,
        password: password_hashed,
        gender,
        phone,
        country: {
          connect: {
            id: country,
          },
        },
        city: {
          connect: {
            id: city,
          },
        },
        address,
        zip,
        dob: date_date_of_birth,
        Roles: {
          connect: {
            id: clientRole.id,
          },
        },
      },
    });

    // generate token to pass to email
    const token = crypto.randomBytes(30).toString("hex");

    await prisma.verify_Account.create({
      data: {
        Users: {
          connect: {
            id: user.id,
          },
        },
        token,
      },
    });

    return res.status(200).json({
      success: true,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return res.status(500).json({
      success: false,
      code: "A00010",
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: Please show what `sendEmailRegistration` do

Comment: You send response in `sendEmailRegistration`. You can't send it again after it. Or the other way around because you never await for `sendEmailRegistration`

Comment: So If I use ```await``` when I call the function will it be okay?

Comment: No, because you still can't send response two times in the same handler

Comment: But how to check if the email or any error has occurred in the email function then?

Comment: Remove `return res.status(200).json({
      success: true,
    });`

Comment: Sounds reasonable, make suggestion as a reply if you want to call it the solution and gets a thumbs up

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254658/discussion-between-n9p4-and-konrad).

Answer (score 0):

This happens when sending a response multiple times to the client. For example, `res.status` and `res.send`.